# PT100 weidmuller transducers output

Tags: transducer

while looking for a PT100 transducer from weidmueller, I faced two types of output current: 4...20 mA and 20...4 mA . Why is it like this? what's the  difference between 4...20 mA output and 20...4 mA ? 
this is the link to the catalogue: http://catalog.weidmueller.com/catalog/Start.do?localeId=hk&ObjectID=1435590000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is not in the PT100 but in the use of the transducer. The output of the transducer can be reversed meaning that with an increase of the PT100 resistance the user can select between decreasing current or increasing current in the loop. This could influence hysteresis behaviour.

On the remark question of OP. The transducer only changes resistance value into different loop currents.

Remark.

After contact with Weidmüller for more information they confirmed the above but were not able to explain the motivation at this time.